# Рисовать в пропорции к PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Рисую`Image` на `PictureBox`, я сделал возможность лепить `Image` пользователю на `PictureBox` самому, чтобы он выбирал место (X, Y) где хочет.

Все работает отлично, но мне нужно чтобы `Image.Size` зависил от розмеров самого `PictureBox`. Я делаю Image к примеру 100 на 100 и ставлю его на `PictureBox` размером 500:500, но вот если уменьшить розмер `PictureBox`, то мне нужно уменьшить `Image.Size` и наоборот.

Как это делать? Мне нужно чтобы `Image`, который прив'язан к координатам мыши изменял размер при изменении размера PictureBox

Comment: Такое подойдёт? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37943359/5045688

Answer (score 0):

Я делал как-то так:

```
    public Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, Size desireSize)
    {

        var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, desireSize.Width, desireSize.Height);
        var destImage = new Bitmap(desireSize.Width, desireSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

        destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
        {
            graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
            {
                wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
            }
        }
        return destImage;
    }
```